# Android: Can't access static elements outside Fragment class

Tags: java, android, exception, null, fragment

I am trying to change elements such TextViews etc. that are parts of the Fragment (which is used for SlidingTabLayout). I can access TextView from the Tab1 class:

```
public class Tab1 extends Fragment {

public static TextView serverName;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_1,container,false);
    serverName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.serverName);
    serverName.setText("This works, but I can't change text from outside the Tab1 class");
    return view;
}
```

But when I want access the serverName TextView from anywhere I am always getting null value. Here I am trying to change the text from the activity which contains Sliding Tabs (Tab1 is a part of it):

```
public class Dashboard2 extends AppCompatActivity {

Toolbar toolbar;
ViewPager pager;
ViewPagerAdapter adapter;
SlidingTabLayout tabs;
CharSequence tabsTitles[] = {"Info", "Options"};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_dashboard2);
    InitializeToolbarAndTabs();
    Tab1.serverName.setText("This doesn't work");
}

private void InitializeToolbarAndTabs()
{
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tool_bar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    adapter =  new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), tabsTitles, tabsTitles.length);

    pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    pager.setAdapter(adapter);

    tabs = (SlidingTabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabs.setDistributeEvenly(true);

    tabs.setCustomTabColorizer(new SlidingTabLayout.TabColorizer() {
        @Override
        public int getIndicatorColor(int position) {
            return getResources().getColor(R.color.tabsScrollColor);
        }
    });

    tabs.setViewPager(pager);
}
```

}

Logs from the Android Studio:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{ASD.Dashboard2}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3119)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3218)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:198)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1676)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6837)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
        at ASD.Dashboard2.onCreate(Dashboard2.java:54)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6500)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1120)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3072)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3218)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:198)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1676)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6837)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
```

*Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference* - how to solve this problem?

Comment: Why not adding some method like getServerName() in the fragment class?

Comment: there is always the same problem, I can't call functions because of the null exception. Creating sliding tabs I was inspired by this tutorial: http://www.android4devs.com/2015/01/how-to-make-material-design-sliding-tabs.html - maybe it will help understanding my problem

Comment: The problem is still not solved. Any ideas how to communicate between main activity and fragment?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are doing but you can always find your fragment by [FragmentManage.findFragmentByTag()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html#findFragmentByTag(java.lang.String)) or FragmentManager.findFragmentById().
Once found just access your field.

Comment: findFragmentByTag() amd ByID() also returns null :( - even List<android.support.v4.app.Fragment> allFragments = getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments(); is null, I mean the List allFragments is null. The Tab1 fragment is one of the tabs in the Dashboard2 activity that contains SlidingTabLayout. I want to edit Tab1 elements from the Dashboard2.

Comment: Have you added your Fragment by means of FragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(...).commit() or replace() ?

Comment: No, I was only following this tutorial: http://www.android4devs.com/2015/01/how-to-make-material-design-sliding-tabs.html

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you have initialized the Tab1 fragment, at least I can't see it there.

Accessing fragment variables from an Activity through static declarations is a horrible idea, use voids in the fragment class.

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry, the error you are getting is not related with accessing or not a static object of the Fragment. The error you are receiving is because at the moment you call `Tab1.serverName.setText("This doesn't work");` your fragment still didnt inflate the view or still didn't charge the TextView (didn't arrive yet to `serverName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.serverName);`). The fragments are charged into the view in a asynchrounous way, so even if you declare it in your layout as a  tag, it may be possible that the Fragment's view is still not fully loaded.

If you absolutely want to be sure the fragment's view is fully loaded, use the `protected void onResumeFragments()` method:

```
@Override
protected void onResumeFragments() {
    super.onResumeFragments();
    Tab1.serverName.setText("This doesn't work");
}
```

Anyway, I strongly recommend you NOT to access fragment objects statically, but to use the `findFragmentById()` or `findFragmentByTag()` methods and then to access a public method inside the given fragment.

Hope it helps.